# MongoDB search in collection

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm a kind of newby in MOngoDB and have the following task. I have a collection in whicn I should get the list of the last uploaded files of all types to the current date, for example for 2016-02-03 . I need the output shows me the time the file was uploaded.

Could you please give me a hint hoe to do it?? Maybe some scripts.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Andrew, and welcome to Stack Overflow. On this site, you aren't supposed to just ask how to put together your code; you're supposed to be developing some code, which you ask questions about, Can you show what you have worked on so far, and to what extent it is working or not? Also showing an example of the structure of data you're working with would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collectionName.find( { contribs: "UNIX" } )
```

For better understanding you can follow the following link.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/