# Latest Mongodb search collection

Tags: php, mongodb

There are currently many conflicting posts regarding mongodb and php due to the driver version. I am using driver 1.2.7, php 5.6 and the latest mongodb on XAMPP

This is my current code:

```
$filter = [ 'userID' => $myUserId, 'isSold' => true];

$cmdOne = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([

    'distinct' => 'collectionNameHere',
    'key' => 'productID',
    'query' => $filter

]);

$cursorOne = $connection->executeCommand('DatabaseNameHere', $cmdOne);

$products = current($cursorOne->toArray())->values;
```

Is there a way to find non-distinct results?

This does not work due to the different mongoDb driver:
[MongoDB search in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973688/mongodb-search-in-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use [executeQuery](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executequery.php) with query filter and projection

```
$filter = [ 'userID' => $myUserId, 'isSold' => true];

$projection = ['projection' => ['productID' => 1]];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $projection);

$cursor = $connection->executeQuery('DatabaseNameHere.CollectionNameHere', $query);
```

Comment: Can you explain the second line please? - mainly what the 1 represents

Comment: 1/ true to include productID in the output. 0/false to exclude. More projection rules here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/